# mysql speed, table index and select/update/insert

Tags: mysql, load, indexing, cpu, myisam

We have got a MySQL table which has got more than 7.000.000 (yes seven million) rows.
We are always doing so much SELECT / INSERT / UPDATE queries per 5 seconds.

Is it a good thing that if we create MySQL INDEX for that table? Will there be some bad consequences like data corrupting or loosing MySQL services etc.?

Little info:

- MySQL version 5.1.56
- Server CentOS
- Table engines are MyISAM
- MySQL CPU load between 200% - 400% always

Comment: I'll bite and ask the obvious: how can *anything* use more than 100 percent of the CPU?

Comment: @PeteWilson - it's probably sum of load on each CPU core. As for the original question - don't use MyISAM, swap to InnoDB and yes, use indexes. As for what to index - no one can tell you that with info you provided.

Answer (score 1):

In general, indexes will improve the speed of SELECT operations and will slow down INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations, as both the base table and the indexes must be modified when a change occurs.

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection? Have I said something incorrect here?

Answer (score 0):

The indexes will help dramatically with selects.  Especially if the match up well with the commonly filtered fields.  And you have a good simple primary key.  They will help with both the time of the queries and the processing cycles.

The drawbacks are if you are **very often** updating/altering/deleting these records, especially the indexed fields.  Even in this case though, it is often worth it.

How much you're going to be reporting (select statement) vs updating (should!) hugely affects both your initial design as well as your later adjustments once your db is in the wild.  Since you already have what you have, testing will give you the answers you need.  If you really do a lot of select queries, and a lot of updating, your solution might be to copy out data now and then to a *reporting table*.  Then you can index like crazy with no ill effects.

You have actually asked a large question, and you should study up on this more.  The general things I've mentioned above hold for most all relational dbs, but there are also particular behaviors of the particular databases (MySQL in your case), mainly in how they decide when and where to use indexes.

Comment: This is only true for the `SELECT` statements. Without knowing the balance between read and write operations, you can't know if adding indexes will help or hurt. If the load is mostly inserts, it could make things _much_ worse.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to say such a thing. I would expect that the indexing itself might take some time. But after that you should have some improvements. As said by @Joe and @Patrick, it might hurt your modification time, but the selecting will be faster.

Ofcourse, there are some other ways of improving performance on inserting and updating. You could ofcourse batch updates if it is not important to have change visible immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for performance, indexes are the way to go. Indexes speed up your queries. If you have 7 Million records, your queries are probably taking many seconds possibley a minute depending on your memory size.

Generally speaking, I would create indexes that match the most frequent SELECT statements. Everyone talks about the negative impact of indexes on table size and speed but I would neglect those impacts unless you have a table for which you are doing 95% of the time inserts and updates but even then, if those inserts happen at night and you query during the day, go and create those indexes, your users during daytime will appreciate it. 
What is the actual time impact to an insert or update statement if there is an additional index, 0.001 secondes maybe? If the index saves you many seconds per each query, I guess the additional time required to update index is well worth it.

The only time I ever had an issue with creating an index (it actually broke the program logic) was when we added a primary key to a table that was previously created (by someone else) without a primary key and the program was expecting that the SELECT statement returns the records in the sequence they were created. Creating the primary key changed that, the records when selecting without any WHERE clause were returned in a different sequence.
This is obviously a wrong design in the first place, nevertheless, if you have an older program and you encounter tables without primary key, I suggest to look at the code that reads that table before adding a primary key, just in case.

One more last thought about creating indexes, the choice of fields and the sequence in which the fields appear in the index have an impact on the performance of the index.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same kind** of problem that you describe.

I did a few changes and 1 query passed from 11sec to a few milliseconds

1- Upgraded to MariaDB 10.1

2- Changed ALL my DB to ARIA engine

3- Changed my.cnf to the strict mininum

4- Upgraded php 7.1 (but this one had a little impact)

5- with CentOS : "Yum update" in the terminal or via ssh (by keeping everything up to date)

---

1- MariaDB is the new Open source version of MYSQL

2- ARIA engine is the evolution of MYISAM

3- my.cnf have usually too much change that affect performance
Here an example

```
[mysqld]
performance-schema=1
general_log=0
slow_query_log=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
```

By removing all extra options from the my.cnf, it's telling mysql to use default values.

In MYSQL 5 (5.1, 5.5, 5.6...) When I did that ; I only noticed a small difference.

But in MariaDB -> the small my.cnf like this did a BIG difference.

******* ALL of those changes ; the server hardware remained the same.

Hope it can help you